# Installing delphichromiumembedded in XE5

Tags: delphi, installation, package, chromium, delphi-xe5

I'm trying hard to install `DelphiChromeEmbedded` into my IDE. I did this so far:

> 1. Double click on "DCEF_D7.dpk".
> 2. From project tree menu, right-click and choose install.

TChromium shows up in the palette but I'm receiving errors when adding it to a new VCL application and running :

> "Cannot resolve unit name 'Cefvcl'".

Looking into the delphichromeembedded /src folder I see that I have a 'Cefvcl' so I guess I should drag and add the src folder to the IDE of the project?

After doing that I get:

[image]

Comment: "D7" in "DCEF_D7.dpk" stands for Delphi 7, you should try "DCEF_XE2.dpk"

Comment: I get 'invalid reference to TControl'... :(

Comment: Isn't there a newer version for XE5 (or XE4 at least)? --> No not yet, try this one: http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/packages/DCEF_XE3.dpk?r=a1e7b4d60764004a22ad54cc2225f6672769afed it's for XE3.

Comment: Still not working, I'm getting error "Exception EOSError in module Project1.exe at 00028B23" when trying to run the app :(

Comment: There is an XE5 package out now, see: https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/packages The checkout link is here: https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/checkout